# html element not being pushed down on media query

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm sure this question has been answered before but most questions say "absolute" positioning is the culprit. I've tried adjusting the positioning, and can't figure out why the P element is not being pushed down.

In my real project, it's the commented out "bannerArea" that needs to be pushed down on the media query, but the background area covers up my navigation menu.

http://codepen.io/fastpenguin91/pen/BLrZBA?editors=1100

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.nav-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 106px;
}
.nav {
  display: table;
}
.primary-nav {
  width: 648px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 4%;
  height: 109px;
}
.listItem {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.listItem {} .logo {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.logo--primary {
  float: left;
}
.primary-nav--content {
  border-left: 2px dashed black;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.test {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
/*
    .bannerArea {
        background: url(../assets/glowgradient.png) no-repeat;
        height: 342px;
        position: relative;
    }*/

/*
    .bannerImg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    
    */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1006px) {
  .nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .primary-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .nav-container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .listItem {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
  }
  .primary-nav--content {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  .logo--primary {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-container">
  <img class="logo  logo--primary" src="assets/logo.png" />
  <ul class="nav  primary-nav  clearfix">
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>HOME</p>
        <p>Back to Home</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>PRODUCTS</p>
        <p>What we have for you</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>SERVICES</p>
        <p>Things we do</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>BLOG</p>
        <p>Follow Our Updates</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>CONTACT</p>
        <p>Ways to reach us</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="test">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<!--
    <div class="bannerArea">

        <img class="bannerImg" src="assets/bannerImg.jpg"/>
    </div> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple.
Add `float` and `width` to the parent:

```
.test {
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Float and width are making the element related to the other elements and therefore it is pushed below the banner.

Comment: Why is that necessary? Div is a block element. shouldn't it by default have a width of 100%, and therefore not need to be floated? Even without that, the list item elements are 100% and should take up the entire width, thus pushing the elements down.

Comment: Actually not, div it's not by default to 100%. Theoretically all browsers are rendering divs as blocks but if you're starting altering the elements around it then it needs to be configured accordingly.

Now on the other hand the element with `.nav-container` class has a fixed height so you can simply not push it.

In my understanding you wanted the pink block to go below so this is the solution I can think of and of course it is W3C validated approach also.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cleared the float for the nav, but not for the logo, which is at the same level of nesting. Add `clear: both;` to the .test style.

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.nav-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 106px;
}
.nav {
  display: table;
}
.primary-nav {
  width: 648px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 4%;
  height: 109px;
}
.listItem {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.listItem {} .logo {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.logo--primary {
  float: left;
}
.primary-nav--content {
  border-left: 2px dashed black;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.test {
  clear: both;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
/*
    .bannerArea {
        background: url(../assets/glowgradient.png) no-repeat;
        height: 342px;
        position: relative;
    }*/

/*
    .bannerImg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    
    */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1006px) {
  .nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .primary-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .nav-container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .listItem {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
  }
  .primary-nav--content {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  .logo--primary {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-container">
  <img class="logo  logo--primary" src="assets/logo.png" />
  <ul class="nav  primary-nav  clearfix">
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>HOME</p>
        <p>Back to Home</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>PRODUCTS</p>
        <p>What we have for you</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>SERVICES</p>
        <p>Things we do</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>BLOG</p>
        <p>Follow Our Updates</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>CONTACT</p>
        <p>Ways to reach us</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="test">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<!--
    <div class="bannerArea">

        <img class="bannerImg" src="assets/bannerImg.jpg"/>
    </div> -->
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution to the OP's problem assuming that the OP wants to avoid removing floats altogether (which would be my preferred solution).

Answer (score 1):

You should *remove* the floats. As a rule they should be avoided entirely and certainly not used for layout. In your case you want the menu to be block level so just *remove* the float:

```
.primary-nav {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0%; /* <- looked weird with left padding */
   height: auto;
   float:none; /* <- don't use floats for layout */
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.nav-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 106px;
}
.nav {
  display: table;
}
.primary-nav {
  width: 648px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 4%;
  height: 109px;
}
.listItem {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.listItem {} .logo {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.logo--primary {
  float: none;/*left*/;
}
.primary-nav--content {
  border-left: 2px dashed black;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.test {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
/*
    .bannerArea {
        background: url(../assets/glowgradient.png) no-repeat;
        height: 342px;
        position: relative;
    }*/

/*
    .bannerImg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    
    */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1006px) {
  .nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .primary-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    height: auto;
    float:none;
  }
  .nav-container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .listItem {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
  }
  .primary-nav--content {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  .logo--primary {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-container">
  <img class="logo  logo--primary" src="assets/logo.png" />
  <ul class="nav  primary-nav  clearfix">
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>HOME</p>
        <p>Back to Home</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>PRODUCTS</p>
        <p>What we have for you</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>SERVICES</p>
        <p>Things we do</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>BLOG</p>
        <p>Follow Our Updates</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <div class="primary-nav--content">
        <p>CONTACT</p>
        <p>Ways to reach us</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="test">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<!--
    <div class="bannerArea">

        <img class="bannerImg" src="assets/bannerImg.jpg"/>
    </div> -->
```

Comment: Thanks Moob. Unfortunately I do need to have the navigation to the right and the logo on the left. I'm converting a PSD file to a responsive HTML document, and the PSD has the nav on the right.

Comment: @JohnCurry understood. However you should still avoid floats for layout. Consider `display:flex` or `inline-block` or `table-cell` solutions instead. It's pretty trivial to have a left/right flexible layout without needing floats. It saves you from this kind of headache too. ;)

Comment: I'm starting to see what you mean as I've progressed further into the project. floats are the only thing that have been giving me problems.